# Google Analytics 4 Only Works In Debug

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to add GA4 to my site alongside Universal Analytics (GA3) - I'm not using Tag Manager.  I've copied the JS from the 'Web stream details' section of the GA console and placed it in the .  The Universal Analytics code loads later in the page and is working as expected - data is visible in the GA console.

Initially I tested the GA4 code using https://tagassistant.google.com/ and all of the events showed up in the debug view in the GA console:

- view_item_list
- select_item
- view_item
- generate_lead
- view_cart
- add_to_cart
- remove_from_cart
- begin_checkout
- add_shipping_info
- add_payment_info
- purchase
- refund

When I opened the dev tools and filter network traffic using 'collect' I can see both GA3 and GA4 events.  If I filter using 'collect?v=2' I only see GA4 events.

If I then open the same site without using https://tagassistant.google.com/ I only see page_view and user_engagement events - none of the above events in the dev tools and they don't show in the GA console - even days later.

I installed a Chrome extension called 'datalayer checker', which shows all of the expected data.  Calling window.dataLayer also shows the same expected data.

In debug view, everything works, when running live it doesn't work.  I've verified that the events contain the required properties.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Or suggest a possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue for the Wordpress. My recommendation to check the developer console and see if you have any errors. Also double check the consent cookie manager if they are blocking the custom events. Thank you!

Comment: I have a similar ongoing issue where I've noticed custom events on GA4 debug view and GTM debug, network tab but not seeing on the GA4 reporting dashboard. I will let you know once I'm able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This week I faced a similar issue, although right in GTM. I know it is a bit different problem, but it might be somehow connected. I at least share my experience and hope it helps someone.

I was hopeless when I checked every setting multiple times and still, everything looked good in debug mode but not in the live version... To my surprise, I found quite basic solutions, which worked for me. The crux of my issue was that I did not have enough rights to publish live version. In the language of GTM permissions, I had only Approve rights not Publish rights. I know it sounds like a stupid mistake, but although I am quite experienced in GTM, I was not able to notice the difference between permissions at first sight. Even with Approve permissions, you are able to publish versions the issue is that it won't go live. The interface and the publishing process look almost the same so it's quite hard to notice when you publish several workspaces during week...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! As a novice, I wasn't even aware of the feature to have a "live" version. Your hint helped me out to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, I encountered a similar challenge myself. Initially, I patiently waited for about 4 to 5 days, anticipating that Google Analytics would begin to register data flow. While the debug mode showcased all activities, the moment it was disconnected, no data appeared. Surprisingly, it wasn't an issue but rather my oversight that led to several days of inconvenience. The misstep was that although I configured the Google Analytics tag and validated its performance in preview mode, I neglected to hit the submit button. Until the tag is submitted, the data flow remains inactive. Hence, if you've successfully integrated GA4, validated it in preview mode, and ensured its functionality, remember to complete the process by submitting it for activation.